# Show convergence in distribution of gamma distribution by the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

So, I'm not sure how to solve this problem:

$X \in \Gamma(a,b)$. Show that $$\frac{X-E[X]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} \rightarrow^{d} N(0,1)$$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$

Use the central limit theorem.

I've come to $\frac{X-ab}{b\sqrt{a}}$, but my feeling is that this is not the same as CLT

$$S_{n} = X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}, n \geq 1$$
$$\frac{S_{n}-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \rightarrow^{d} N(0,1)$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

since $S_{n}$ is a sum of r.v.'s and $X$ is a single r.v..

Comment: Hint: For any positive integer $n$, $X \sim \Gamma(n,b)$ is the sum of $n$ independent $\Gamma(1,b)$, that is, _exponential_ random variables $Y_i$. So, replace $X$ by $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ and go from there.

Comment: So if I understand you right, it should be like this:

$Y_{i} \in Exp(b)$
$$\Gamma (a,) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{a} Y_{i}$$

$$E[\Sigma_{i=1}^{a} Y_{i}] = \Sigma_{i=1}^{a} E[Y_{i}] = ab = a\mu$$


$$Var[\Sigma_{i=1}^{a} Y_{i}] = \Sigma_{i=1}^{a} Var[Y_{i}] = ab^{2} = a\sigma^{2}$$

$$\frac{S_{a} - a\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{a}} \rightarrow^{d} N{0,1}$$

Comment: Yes, that is the general idea, except that $\sum_{i=}^a$ does not make sense unless $a$ is an integer. That's why I wrote $n$ instead of $a$.